# Drop records not aligning with Schema: Parquet: Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Spark scala**

I have a directory in azure blob storage. It has parquet files.
AId | BId | UpdatedTime

Due to some code issue, there are two types of values in UpdatedTime. Some records are of string type and some are timestamp type.
I want to read only the records that have string datatype in my dataframe. Below code is not working and still throwing exception: Expected string found Int96.

```
 val myschema = new StructType().
                add("AId", StringType, true).
                add("BId", StringType, true).
                add("UpdatedTime", StringType, true)
 
 spark.read.format("parquet").
        option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").  
        schema(myschema).
        load(path)
```

Exception:

Command finishedat 05-26-2021 03:13:35.093 -07:00, execution took 19s 410ms
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, wn17-o365ma.2ltx0s20kdeufjhsteurve1kdf.dx.internal.cloudapp.net, executor 30):
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file abfs://root@acc.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/directory/part-00072-0e119bb6-4ec8-436c-bf23-34dad8c28e4c.c000.snappy.parquet. Column: [lastUpdated], Expected: string, Found: INT96
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.constructConvertNotSupportedException(VectorizedColumnReader.java:250)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.decodeDictionaryIds(VectorizedColumnReader.java:343)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
... 23 more

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Comment: added in question

Comment: @SakshiKochhar, did you ever figure it out? I have a similar issue...